# iOS Navigation bar is getting hided when scrolling (is kind of scrolling too), regardless it is outside the scroll view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm having issues with the navigation bar, I want to set a view controller where there is a scroll view with its content, but I'm having a weird behavior that when I scroll down the navigation bar hides kind of scrolling with the scroll view but the navigation bar is not inside that.

My Scroll view has a vertical spacing to the top to avoid going upper that I want and hiding the navigation bar but it still happens.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess your scrollview has a vertical spacing to your something else other then the top margin. Can you post some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `hidesBarsOnSwipe = false` for the navigation contrller.

More info from [Apple api reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621883-hidesbarsonswipe)